# Is there something I can do to help unlock my answer? And what happens if I don't?

Tags: support, moderators, specific-answer

A comment by ymb1 on an answer to my related question [Can a locked thread be upvoted?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3660/can-a-locked-thread-be-upvoted/3663#3663) suggested I ought to raise the issue of my locked answer [Which parts of class E airspace can an ultralight (part 103) fly in without prior ATC authorization?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35297/which-parts-of-class-e-airspace-can-an-ultralight-part-103-fly-in-without-prio/55714#55714) . That's news to me; I wasn't aware that the banner "This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved. For more info visit meta." meant that I was supposed to post something here.  I tried looking around for some sort of tab or button that would give info on why my specific answer was locked but didn't find anything.  Thanks for the pointer ymb1.

ymb1 suggested "Edit your question above about your intentions with the post if it were to be unlocked after reading my answer"

I don't feel that really belongs in my other question so I'll create this one.

Ok, my intention would be to greatly slow down the edits-- wait until I have a significant edit to make, consisting of actual new content to add, and include all minor edits at that time, and no more than say monthly in most cases, and likely with many months or even longer between edits.

Be aware that there is very high chance that new legislation will go into effect within the next 3-12 months that will bear directly on my answer.  A friend of mine is also seeking an official interpretation from the FAA that will bear directly on my answer.  So I am not saying that I would never wish to edit the answer again.

The truth is a new interpretation from the FAA might allow the answer to be radically streamlined.  It would be a shame not to be able to do that.

OK, there you go-- trying to follow ymb1's suggestion as best I understand it-- am I doing the right thing here or should I be doing something different?

I'm not really that worried about it as I'm happy to have it up there just as it stands right now but figured might as well try to get it unlocked.

Added component to question-- if I just do nothing does it just stay up there, locked, indefinitely, or what else might happen?

And how can I find out what the specific objections are anyway, if they encompass anything beyond too frequent editing, as the last comment that appeared before the thread was locked, made by the person who locked it, suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked you to stop the edits when you where at 28 edits. You agreed. And then proceeded to make 50 more. I'm not sure we agree on the meaning of "slowing down the edits" at this point, since you are replicating the behaviour on other two answers of yours.

And many of these edits are completely minor and not needed, and moreover made a few minutes apart.

Also, one of the comments after mine asked you to make the answer **shorter** and you made edits to *add sections*. Again, I'm not sure what to make of that.

All of this tells me that you yourself do not know what your answer should be, hence the "content dispute".

The lock does not need to be permanent, but we want to see that you understand the problems you are creating with your continuous editing:

- it continuously bumps the question on the homepage, starving other posts of attention
- it does not allow a reader to see the "final version" of the answer, because 5 minutes later it will be edited again
- it is extremely long. If such a long answer was really needed, you should not write it, but rater close the question as too broad

I am ready to unlock your answer, but I will only tolerate one more edit, and it must significantly shorten the answer. If the regulation will change in 3-12 months, we will have a look at it in 3-12 months, not 3-12 minutes, and also then, one edit.

80 edits on an answer are an excessive amount, particularly if done in disregard of a moderator request.

Comment: Apologies.  Please keep in mind I am new here and don't know who runs things-- who is making an authoritative command as a moderator and who is just giving an opinion.  I was not aware that you were a moderator.  Alright, only one edit.  Can I give it a few days to make sure I am happy with it?  Do you have a specific time limit in mind?  Is the point that it must be shortened or just that it must not be edited unless the edit shortens it?  I'd like to comply with your request so if you could clarify that last bit I would appreciate it.  Thank you for the consideration.

Comment: @quietflyer there is no time limit, take all the time you need. Please leave in there only what is strictly necessary to answer the question that was asked.

Comment: It's hard for me to not to reedit frequently in the first hour or two after posting, it's just the way I work, new ideas keep coming up, but I will make much stricter efforts to not keep bumping a post up to the top in 6, 12, 24, 48 hours later, etc. Likewise will  make efforts to type up answer on notepad or whatever first and sit on it a day before posting again to keep edits to a minimum.  Thank you again for your consideration.

Comment: @quietflyer if you need 1-2 hours to settle on a version, ymb1 suggestion to write it first offline is a good one.

Comment: Ok. I was typing that at the same time as you were.